# Path generated via subst-command not found by System.IO

Tags: c#, .net

context:

- System has one Harddisk with one drive ("C:\")
- The needed path is located at F:\eventlogging

What I have done:

- I executed the subst cmd in order to generate the F:\ drive (from C:\)
- Added the directory "eventlogging"

The problem:

- In the code, there are parts in which it writes to a file inside of F:\eventlogging
- Exception gets thrown: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 
  'F:\eventlogging\'..

What I tried:

- Entering the path in the explorer works (goes to path)
- cd in cmd to this path works as well

Additional info:

- Code can not be changed (common base for many projects)

Comment: Have you tried mapping C to F not subst? Although I mapped my C to E (as F was taken) and Directory.Exists("E:\\inetpub\\") worked for me. Im on Win7 mind

Comment: @Pikoh: changing the system drive letter would be a *really* bad idea. :)

Comment: @Groo you are absolutely right! I don't know what I was thinking about :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mapped the drive with an elevated prompt, it will be invisible under non-admin accounts.

You can either run your program as an adminstrator, or use a different method which is visible to both admin and non-admin accounts. This involves adding the following key to the registry (copy/paste the following line into a `"temp.reg"` file, and double-click it):

```
REGEDIT4 

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\DOS Devices] 
"F:"="\\??\\C:"
```

Additional benefit is that this approach is persistent across reboots.

**Note:** If you are planning to add the key manually using regedit.exe, do not escape the backslashes (i.e. replace each `\\` with `\` in the expression above), and there are no quotes in that case too (you would add a new `String Value` to the `DOS Devices` key, set name to `F:`, and data to `\??\C:`)

You also need to restart the system for this to take effect.

Also: I am aware you wrote that the code cannot be changed, but it should be emphasized nevertheless: using a config file instead of hard-coded paths would obviously be the right approach with any application (or even simpler, placing logs somewhere inside current users `AppData\Local` folder). Rebuilding this common base with a default set to `f:\eventlogging` wouldn't break other apps, but would allow you to have this flexibility. Same goes for all other hard-coded settings and magic numbers across your code. All logging frameworks use config files to configure their outputs.

Comment: Hello Groo and thanks for your detailed answer.
I subst´ed the Drive with an elevated prompt and VS2015 is also running elevated... I will try the second way and will tell you if it worked :)

Comment: Worked, thank you very much! Adding to the reg did it